# Typescript return HTML Template Element from Constructor typing not working

Tags: html, typescript, dom

It is 'illegal' to use `new` when creating an instance of `Template`, where `Template` extends an `HTMLTemplateElement`.

To overcome this limitation, I get and return an `HTMLTemplateElement` using `document.getElementById(id)` from the `Template` constructor as below:

```js
export class Template {
    private htmlTemplateElement: HTMLTemplateElement;
    constructor(id: string) {
        this.htmlTemplateElement = document.getElementById(id) as HTMLTemplateElement;
        return Object.assign(this.htmlTemplateElement, this) 
    }

    public test = () => this.htmlTemplateElement.innerHTML
}
```

Providing an `HTML Template Element` exist in the DOM,
I can create a new instance of `Template` and use the extension method `test()` as illustrated below:

```js
const template = new Template(id)
console.log(template.test())
console.log(template.innerHTML)
```

Both `console.log()` works just fine and prints the correct text to the console.

**HOWEVER**, the typescript compiler complains about `template.innerHTML`.
The error I get, saying `innerHTML` does not exist on type `Template`

**Question:** How can I add type information so I do not get a compiler error?

I have tried to use `export class Template extends HTMLTemplateElement`.
That does not work since it is `illegal` to create an instance using `new`.

I love typescript, but sometimes the type checking gets in my way.
Help me out here, please.

Comment: Typescript (AFAIK) does not support returning alternative values from constructors in classes. "That does not work since it is illegal to create an instance using new" that is correct, if you want to extend an element you have to call [`customElements.define`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry) and construct it in DOM, not JS. Then you can grab the instance by querying the DOM to manipulate in JS.

Comment: This kinda seems like it might be an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you *actually* trying to do here?

Comment: @JaredSmith my goal is to get the typescript compiler happy. The javascript works just fine. Also, my end goal is to add several methods not only the `test` method above, but that is not really the problem I am trying to solve here.

Comment: What I'm trying to tell you is that the TS compiler ain't gonna be happy. You can either turn it off by laboriously casting or `@ts-ignoring` ***every*** place you use that type, or you can rewrite your code to work with it. As for the JS working fine, if I saw that in a code review I'd flag it and tell you to use `customElements.define` to properly extend an HTML element. As to whether or not it's worth the effort to change it (particularly if it's already in production as-is) is a call you're going to have to make, but I've already shown you the path if you choose to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Although not ideal, I was able to keep the typescript compiler happy by implementing the following interface:

```js
export interface ITemplate {
    [key:string]: any;
    test(): string;
}
```

and then using the interface:

```js
export Template implements ITemplate {
...
}
```

**Note:**
Why did I not use `customElements.define(<tag-name>,Template)`?
I do not intend to create a **new** custom instance of `HTMLTemplateElement`, I just want to return an existing `HTMLTemplateElement` with additional utility extension methods.

Also, It might very well be possible that my approach is completely wrong.
However, that is a different topic than the question asked here.